# Menu not working properly

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //for the clear screen function
#include <string.h>

struct customer
{
    int custID;
    char custName[50];
    char custAddress[100];
};

typedef struct customer c;

void load_menu(void);
void customers_menu(void);
void createNew(void); //initialize your file
void add_Customer(c c1[30]); //add a new record to the file
FILE *fp;



int main(void)
{

load_menu();
return 0;
}

void load_menu(void)
{
int choice;

do
{
    printf("Customer Orders Main Menu. \n\n");
            printf("Please enter your choice: \n");
    printf("1. Customer's Menu \n");
    printf("2. Orders Menu\n");
    printf("3. Product Stock Menu\n");
    printf("4. Exit\n");
    printf("\n");
    if (scanf("%d",&choice)==1)
    {

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: system ("cls");
                    customers_menu();
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
            case 2: system ("cls");
                    orders_menu();
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
            case 3: system ("cls");
                    stock_menu();
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
            case 4: printf("Quitting program!\n");
                    break;
            default: printf("Invalid choice! Please try again\n");
                    printf("\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Characters are invalid, please enter a number: \n ");
        choice=0;
    }

}while((choice !=4));
}




void createNew(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("Customer.dat", "w");
    if (fp==NULL)
        printf("File creation failed! \n");
    else
    {
        printf("File created! \n");
        fclose(fp);
    }

}

void add_Customer (c c1[30])
{
    int i, n , cc=0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("Customer.dat", "a");
    system("cls");

    if(fp==NULL)
   {
       printf("File Creation Failed!");
   }
   system("cls");

   printf("Enter the number of Customers: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       printf("Customer's ID (numbers only)  : ");
       scanf("%d", &c1[i].custID);

       printf("Customer's  Name              : ");
       gets(c1[i].custName);

        printf("Customer's Address            : ");
        gets(c1[i].custAddress);



        fwrite(&c1[i], sizeof(c), 1, fp);
    }cc++;

    fclose(fp);
}

void recordCount(c c1[30], int *count)
{
    add_Customer(c1);
    count=0;
    count++;
}

void customers_menu(void)
{
int choice;
    c c1[30];
    int i;


do
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("Customers Menu \n\n");
    printf("Please enter your choice: \n");
    printf("1. Add Customer \n");
    printf("2.\n");
    printf("3.\n");
    printf("4. Go back to Main Menu \n");
    recordCount (c1, &i);

    if (scanf("%d",&choice)==1)
    {

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: add_Customer(c1);
                    createNew();

                    printf("\n");
                    break;
            case 2:
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
            case 3:
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
            case 4: printf("Going back to Main Menu\n");
                    system ("cls");
                    break;
            default: printf("Invalid choice! Please try again\n");
                    printf("\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Characters are invalid, please enter a number: \n ");
        choice=0;
    }

}while((choice !=4));
```

I have a problem since when I enter the Customers Menu it is staring to execute case 1 immediately (which still doesn't work properly). Can someone help me fix this error please because I tried everything I know and it is still in vain

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand your description of the problem. Your switch statements seem fine. What input causes the erroneous behavior?

Comment: Sanity check: just inside your if block, put `printf("%d", choice);` to see what is actually read.

Comment: It probably doesn't. In `customers_menu`, you call `recordCount` which calls `add_Customer`. Also, keep in mind that your first `gets` call will return immediately because the new line of the preceding `scanf` call will still be in the input buffer.

Comment: how should i fix the problem then? :S

Comment: It's not clear why you call `add_Customer` from `recordCount` so I can't really tell until you tell us exactly what this is supposed to do.

Comment: Some comments: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour. fflush is defined only for ostream. Don't use `gets()` "It's dangerous & should not be used."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that in `customers_menu()` you output the menu, but do not read the selection, instead you call `recordCount()` which directly calls `addCustomer()`.

After `addCustomer()` we return the `customers_menu()` which then calls `scanf()` for the long gone menu.

A few other notes:

1. `gets()` is not good, I suggest you use `scanf()` (with %s) instead.
2. Doing a `printf()` then clearing the screen is a bit pointless.
3. Error messages should really go to stderr (fprintf(stderr,...)) rather than stdout (printf(...))
4. You code is a missing trailing }.
5. cc is added to, but not used.

Comment: I read the choice in the customer_menu by this: if (scanf("%d",&choice)==1

Comment: Yes, but that is *after* you call `recordCount()`.

Answer (score 1):

This problem coming from `if (scanf("%d",&choice)==1)` because `scanf` will not return choice. If you enter valid answer (like number), then it returns 1 and switch case work with 1. I think that's the problem.
If you enter char instead of integer, `scanf` will return 0.

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of args it was able to match from stdin. It doesn't return the input itself, the way `getchar()` does. In this case it should always return `1`, assuming everything was fine.